# Extract prefix from string in dataframe column where exists in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for some help.
I have a pandas dataframe column  and I want to extract the prefix where such prefix exists in a separate list.

```
pr_list = ['1 FO-','2 IA-']
```

Column in df is like

```
PartNumber     
ABC
DEF
1 FO-BLABLA
2 IA-EXAMPLE
```

What I am looking for is to extract the prefix where present, put in a new column and leave the rest of the string in the original column.

```
PartNumber   Prefix
ABC          
DEF
BLABLA       1 FO-
EXAMPLE      2 IA-
```

Have tried some things like str.startswith but a bit of a python novice and wasn't able to get it to work.

much appreciated

**EDIT**
Both solutions below work on the test data, however I am getting an error
**error: nothing to repeat at position 16**
Which suggests something askew in my dataset. Not sure what position 16 refers to but looking at both the prefix list and PartNumber column in position 16 nothing seems out of the ordinary?

**EDIT 2**
I have traced it to have an * in the pr_list seems to be throwing it. is * some reserved character? is there a way to break it out so it is read as text?

Comment: Are all the prefix ending with '-'? In this case you could try to play from df["PartNumber"].str.split("-")

Comment: No unfortunately, can be anything from a single digit, to special characters like *SV, which is why I went with the list route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not what you are looking for, but may it help.

```
import pandas as pd

pr_list = ['1 FO-','2 IA-']
df = pd.DataFrame({'PartNumber':['ABC','DEF','1 FO-BLABLA','2 IA-EXAMPLE']})

extr = '|'.join(x for x in pr_list)
df['Prefix'] = df['PartNumber'].str.extract('('+ extr + ')', expand=False).fillna('')
df['PartNumber'] = df['PartNumber'].str.replace('|'.join(pr_list),'')
df
```

Comment: Your solution works great on the sample data I provided, however when I apply it to the full dataset, I get an error
**error: nothing to repeat at position 16**
This something to do with my data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['Prefix']=df.PartNumber.str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(pr_list))).fillna('')
df.PartNumber=df.PartNumber.str.replace('|'.join(pr_list),'')
print(df)

  PartNumber Prefix
0        ABC       
1        DEF       
2     BLABLA  1 FO-
3    EXAMPLE  2 IA-
```

Comment: Hi Anky, again your solution works on the test data but I am getting the **error: nothing to repeat at position 16** problem so it must be my data. Unsure of this error if you have any idea?